# How to achieve Full width LongTable in MDPI Template in LaTeX?

Tags: longtable, adjustwidth, mdpi

I am using the following piece of code in [MDPI Template](https://www.overleaf.com/4247568723sfhzdwzywfds):

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,pdftex,moreauthors]{Definitions/mdpi} 


\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

% It doesn't give full width.
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\extralength}{0cm}
\begin{longtable}{| l | l | l | l |}
abc & abc & abc & abc
\end{longtable}

% It gives full width table.
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\extralength}{0cm}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l |}
abc & abc & abc & abc
\end{tabular}

\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't give me the full-width longtable.

Comment: the long table manual has an example showing how to use extracolsep to force a longtable width

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: In particular, please be more precise regarding "MDPI template in LaTeX". E.g., do you mean to refer to the `mdpi` document class? If so, should the document class be loaded with certain options?

Comment: I have attached the Link to overleaf document.
It's the basic MDPI template available on overleaf.

Comment: Hi guys, I have updated my question. @Mico you're right. I am referring to `mdpi` document class.

Comment: @Mico I replied to your answer.

Comment: @MFaizan - My answer *on purpose* doesn't give any shrift to the `adjustbox` sledgehammer approach. If you want to leave a *comment* below my answer, feel free to do so. However, please don't attempt to *edit* my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your query isn't specific to the `mdpi` document class.

As @DavidCarlisle has already suggested doing in a comment, do please check out section 5, entitled "Adjustment", of the user guide of the `longtable` package for suggestions for achieving your formatting objective.

The only thing the user guide doesn't mention is that when you employ the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` spacing device, you shouldn't employ vertical rules in the `longtable`. Of course, employing vertical rules in a table is something one shouldn't do anyway.

Summing up: Do change

```
\begin{longtable}{| l | l | l | l |}
\hline
abc & abc & abc & abc \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

to

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} llll @{}}
\hline
abc & abc & abc & abc \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

[image]